# How can I set tic-mark labels in the DMS (deg° min′ sec″) format?

Tags: gnuplot

Suppose I'm plotting some geographic data in gnuplot, and I'd like to set tic-mark labels in the DMS (deg°min′sec″) format; e.g.

```
37°31′40″N
37°31′20″N
37°31′00″N
37°30′40″N
37°30′20″N
37°30′00″N
```

without creating lots of custom labels manually. Is this possible? How can I do this?

Comment: That is supported only in the development version, which knows a `set xdata geographic`. Maybe you can simplify creating the manual labels with iterations: `set for [i=0:10] xtics add ...`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot of the terminal you're using. On a mac with aqua terminal, this works:

```
set timefmt "%Y°%M′%S″N"
set format x "%y˚%M\'%S\"N"
set xdata time
plot 'test.dat' u 1:0
```

Comment: I tried it, and it doesn't work.
The manual says `timefmt` only tells _how to read timedata from the datafile_, so I don't think it should matter here. I don't understand why you used `%Y` or `%y`, but they are simply displayed as zero. `%M` and `%S` don't get correct values, either.